# Stored procedure : getting error "Must declare the scalar variable "@id". " when executing procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I need some help creating a stored procedure in SQL Server.

This is my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_TABLE_ELEMENTS] 
    @id nvarchar(max)
AS
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = '', @col_list varchar(max) = ''

    SET @col_list = (SELECT DISTINCT QOUTENAME(columnName) + ',' 
                     FROM VW_FORM_ELEMENTS_DATA
                     FOR XML PATH(''))

    SET @col_list = LEFT(@col_list, LEN(@col_list) - 1)

    SET @sql = N'SELECT [newId], [modifiedDate], [modifiedBy], [modifiedBy]' + @col_list + 
                ' FROM (SELECT newId, value, columnName, modifiedDate, modifiedBy 
                        FROM VW_FORM_ELEMENTS_DATA 
                        WHERE newId = @id) a
                  PIVOT
                      (MAX([value]) FOR [columnName] IN (' + @col_list + ')) pv'

    EXEC (@sql)
```

I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

Comment: Add `@id` as a parameter to the [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement. Otherwise the value isn't available to the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Please share sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: big thanks. kazi that was really helpful.

Comment: there was a problem running it

Comment: @ChristianLacuesta you might have accidentally cancelled accepted result.

Comment: That's ok. no problem at all. But in screen shot you can see that it worked. best of luck.

Comment: Please don't use images to display text. For code and results/errors just show the formatted text. Easier for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_TABLE_ELEMENTS] 
@id nvarchar(max)
AS

declare @sql varchar(max)='',@col_list varchar(max)=''


set @col_list = (select distinct quotename(columnName)+',' from VW_FORM_ELEMENTS_DATA
for xml path(''))

set @col_list = left (@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)


set @sql = 'select [screenId],[newId],[modifiedDate],[modifiedBy],[modifiedBy]'+@col_list+' from
(SELECT screenId, newId, value, columnName, modifiedDate, modifiedBy FROM VW_FORM_ELEMENTS_DATA where screenId = ''' + @id + ''') a
pivot (max([value]) for [columnName] in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: this solution will only work if there is only 1 result set